# login validation show an alert if the user entered the wrong login information

Tags: php

I need to echo or to show an alert box when the user entered a incorrect user name and password. I used the url for the mean time to show the status if the user entered the incorrect username or the incorrect password.

```
session_start();


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string ($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    //ERROR HANDLERS
    //Check for empty fields

    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../login.php?login=empty");
    exit();
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
        header("Location: ../login.php?username_not_found");
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //De-hashing the password
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                header("Location: ../login.php?password_not_match");
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {
                //Log in the user here
                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['u_first'] = $row['user_first'];
                $_SESSION['u_last'] = $row['user_last'];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['user_email'];
                $_SESSION['u_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];

                header("Location: ../apptableremarks.php?login=success");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}

} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?login=error");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You should get by POST the login parameter and check if it's error, then you can show an alertbox by JavaScript or showing an html/css alertbox as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first change this line

```
header("Location: ../login.php?login=notFound");
```

then on the top the page in index.php file write this code

```
if(isset($_GET['login']))
{
    echo "user name not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should pass header variable like this :**

`header("Location: ../login.php?user=not_found");`

and then you can grab it using $_GET[] variable.

**Like this:** `if(isset($_GET["user"] && $_GET["user"]==="not_fount")) echo "your alert message";`